# WPF Element Binding not working in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

This should be fairly simple and straightforward but element binding is not working in XAML when using it from resource. It is working fine when using it directly in XAML.

**Resources:**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel x:Key="panel">
        <CheckBox x:Name="chkDefaultValue" Content="Default Value"  
                  IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=txtDefaultValue, Path=Text.Length, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtDefaultValue"
                  Text="{Binding DefaultValue, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                  IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=chkDefaultValue, Path=IsChecked}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window.Resources>
```

**XAML:**

```
<StackPanel>
    <!-- BINDING NOT WORKING -->
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource panel}" />

    <!-- BINDING WORKING HERE -->
    <CheckBox x:Name="chkDefaultValue" Content="Default Value"  
              IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=txtDefaultValue, Path=Text.Length, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <TextBox x:Name="txtDefaultValue"
              Text="{Binding DefaultValue, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
              IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=chkDefaultValue, Path=IsChecked}" />
</StackPanel>
```

How could i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `DataTemplate`

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ContentControl}" x:Key="panel">
       <StackPanel>
             <CheckBox x:Name="chkDefaultValue" Content="Default Value"  
              IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=txtDefaultValue, Path=Text.Length, Mode=OneWay}" />
             <TextBox x:Name="txtDefaultValue"
              Text="{Binding DefaultValue, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
              IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=chkDefaultValue, Path=IsChecked}" />
       </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

and

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource panel}" />
```

didn't check, but probably works

Answer (score 1):

And you can use ControlTemplate

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="panel">
        <StackPanel>
            <CheckBox x:Name="chkDefaultValue"
                      Content="Default Value"
                      IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=txtDefaultValue,
                                          Path=Text.Length,
                                          Mode=OneWay}" />
            <TextBox x:Name="txtDefaultValue"
                     IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=chkDefaultValue,
                                         Path=IsChecked}"
                     Text="{Binding DefaultValue,
                                    Mode=TwoWay,
                                    ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

and

```
<ContentControl Template="{StaticResource panel}" />
```